# Error establishing direct connection to mongo node at [ip:port]. Error output: no reachable servers and SASl

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, metrics, elk, metricbeat

I am using MongoDB with a replica set. When I am trying to create a metricbeat MongoDB module am not sure How to give a URL. I don't understand how to solve it. when uncommenting the `ssl.verification_mode: 'none'` then getting `"no reachable servers error"`. if you comment the `ssl.verification_mode: 'none'` then getting `saslcontinue.mechanism error`.

metricbeat version: 7.11.1
MongoDB: 5.0

> #ssl.verification_mode: 'none' mongodb/mongodb.go:98 Error establishing direct connection to mongo node at [ip:27017]. Error
> output: server returned error on SASL authentication step: BSON field
> 'saslContinue.mechanism' is an unknown field. module/wrapper.go:259
> Error fetching data for metric set mongodb.status: error creating new
> Session: server returned error on SASL authentication step: BSON field
> 'saslContinue.mechanism' is an unknown field.
>
> ssl.verification_mode: 'none':
>
> "error": { "message": "error creating new Session: no reachable
> servers"